# The view app.views.model didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py file. i am on the way to generate xml file, The data i am getting from mysql. First time its working but i make some changes then i cant remember what i did now it s not working ...

in the views.py

```
def MessageHeaderModel2(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = MessageHeaderForm(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                            DDEX_Party_Id = request.POST.get('DDEX_Party_Id',None)
                            data = serializers.serialize("xml", MessageHeaderModel2.objects.all())
                            with open("file.xml", "w") as out:
                            xml_serializer.serialize(MessageHeaderModel2.obj    ects.all(), stream=out)
```

The error now i am gettin is

```
>Exception Type:ValueError
Exception Value:The view app.views.MessageHeaderModel2 didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You in fact are not returning an `HttpResponse` object!

Django views must return an instance of `HttpResponse` so at the end of your view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def view(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponse("the page content")
```

You can also return may other subclasses of `HttpResponse`, see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses) for a list.

You can also use some of the shortcut functions to render a page using the django templating system, again the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/) is helpful here, but briefly:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def view(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

A complete example using your code from above:

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MessageHeaderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            DDEX_Party_Id = request.POST.get('DDEX_Party_Id',None)
            data = serializers.serialize("xml", MessageHeaderModel2.objects.all())
            with open("file.xml", "w") as out:
                out.write(data)
            return HttpResponse(data)
        else:
            # return error response?
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
```

Comment: i gave like return HttpResponse("file.xml") .. Then also not working same error

Comment: You must return an `HttpResponse` on all code paths. I'm guessing you are only returning it when `request.method == "POST"`? If the page is designed to **only** accept POST requests, you can `return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])` after your `if` block.

Comment: If you want to return the contents of your generated XML, then you don't want to save it to file at all.

Comment: You want to save it as well as return it to the browser?

Comment: See my edit, but I why on earth do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Like stated in the error, your view isn't sending any response to the client.

Add at the end of your view a line like :

```
return render(request, 'template.html')
```

Or any other response, that you need

Comment: shall i give return render(request,'file.xml') ..?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything so that's why you have such an error...

You can also for example return Success value or redirect to other view..